# can not import MySQLdb after I installed it in a virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv, mysql-connector

system:ubuntu14.04, mysql:5.5, python:2.7.4

I have installed mysql-connector-python outside of a virtualenv using this command：

```
pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

I can use mysql-connector correctly outside of the virtualenv:

```
think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> 
>>>
```

then I activated a virtualenv and installed the mysql-connector. I used this method(I downloaded this install package from the offical website):

```
    think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ cd ~/download/
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/download$ dpkg -i mysql-connector-python_2.0.4-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb
```

After installed it correctly, I can not import it:

```
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/download$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

I don't know why, then I had to install MySQLdb inside the virtualenv:

```
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

after finished it, I can not import it too

```
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

then I installed MySQL-python and libmysqlclient-dev, it alse didn't work.

then I looked over the venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages:

```
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
easy_install.py   pip-7.1.2.dist-info        wheel
easy_install.pyc  pkg_resources              wheel-0.24.0.dist-info
_markerlib        setuptools
pip               setuptools-18.2.dist-info
```

there are not mysql-connector or mysqldb, I find mysqlconnector in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages when I tried to reinstall mysqlconnector,

```
(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ sudo pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
[sudo] password for think: 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-connector-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I really don't know how to do after I install mysql-connector-python,mysqldb,mysql-python and libmysqlclient-dev. I can use them outside of the virtualenv, but I still can not import mysql-connector nor mysqldb in virtualenv.

Please help me: how can I connect mysql in virtualenv? thanks very much. (if the expression is not clear, tell me and I will update it,thanks)

Comment: @Youn Elan thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then I activated a virtualenv and installed the mysql-connector (...)
>   `dpkg -i mysql-connector-python_2.0.4-1ubuntu14.04_all.deb`
>   (...)
>   then I had to install MySQLdb inside the virtualenv:
>   `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Err... `apt-get` and `dpkg` are your distrib's package manager, this has nothing to do with `pip` and virtualenv. Your distrib's package manager installs system packages (.deb in your case) and install them system-wide. The point of `virtualenv` is to install *python* packages (with `pip`) in an isolated "virtual" environnement. What you want is:

```
# source path/to/your/venv/bin/activate
# pip install your-python-package
```

Note that all this is documented in `virtualenv` and `pip`...

Comment: Oh I see, thanks very much. But why it returned `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-connector-python in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` when I used `(venv)think@think-Inspiron-N4050:~/myzone/MindFly$ sudo pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python`, I have activated the virtualenv